# Nodejs Code in Visual Studio 2015 throws error but works from node command line. Unexpected token =>

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2015, ntvs

I have a function in node js script which works fine when I am using node command line to start my project:

However when I run the project from visual studio 2015, I get this Error :

> Debugger listening on port 5858 C:\nodejs\Apps\EMIApp\config\dal.js:69
>                           response => { db.close();
>                                    ^^
>
> > SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
> >
> > ```
> > at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
> >
> > at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
> >
> > at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
> >
> > at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
> >
> > at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
> >
> > at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
> >
> > at require (module.js:384:17)
> >
> > at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\Apps\EMIApp\Server.js:5:12)
> >
> > at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
> >
> > at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10) Press any key to continue...
> > ```

The code sample which has error is :

```
function connectDB (callback)
{
    // Use connect method to connect to the Server
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

  if (err) //Return if any Error.
  {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    callback(err,null);
    return;
  }

    //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
    console.log('Connection established to', url);

  //Call the callback function provided & once done, close the connection from here. do not trust callback
    callback(err,db).then(
            response => { db.close();  **//This Line**
                            console.log("db closed");
                        },
            reject => {
                        console.log("Some Error in Callback");
                         try 
                         {
                             db.close();                             
                         }catch(e)
                         {           
                             console.log(e);
                         }
                      }
            );
    }); 
}
```

I think Visual Studio 2015 is unable to resolve this symbol  **=>** .
Any ideas on how to make this work in visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally managed to find the issue.

Visual Studio 2015 installed Node Version **v0.12.2** at **C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs.**

& I had another node installed (separately before vs 2015 installation ) at **c:\nodejs** Which was version **v4.4.3.**

In the **properties page of the project,** I changed the path of node.exe to point to the latest one.